# reactjs onClick doesn't update the activeIndex why it works onDoubleCLick?

Tags: reactjs

To store active index

```
 const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
```

All Links in Navbar

```
     <Link to="booking" key={1} onClick={() =>  setActiveIndex(1)}>
          <ListItem button className={ (activeIndex === 1 )? classes.activeclass : null}>
            <ListItemIcon><HomeOutlinedIcon fontSize="large"/></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText><h5>Booking</h5></ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
        </Link>

       
        <Link to="dashboard" key={2} onClick={() =>  setActiveIndex(2)} >
          <ListItem button className={ (activeIndex === 2 )? classes.activeclass : null}>
            <ListItemIcon><DashboardOutlinedIcon fontSize="large" /></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText><h5>Dashboard</h5></ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
        </Link>
       
        
        <Link to="parking" key={3} onClick={() =>  setActiveIndex(3)}>
          <ListItem button className={ (activeIndex === 3 )? classes.activeclass : null}>
            <ListItemIcon><PinDropTwoToneIcon fontSize="large" /></ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText>Parking Area</ListItemText>
          </ListItem>
        </Link> 
        
        <Link to="gateList" key={4} onClick={() =>  setActiveIndex(4)}>
       <ListItem button className={ (activeIndex === 4 )? classes.activeclass : null}>
       <ListItemIcon><ListAltOutlinedIcon fontSize="large" /></ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText><h5>GateList</h5></ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
       </Link>
```

Link is not active onClick, it gets active when doubleClick.

Why do I need to press twice to make `activeIndex` active?

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Comment: no I need to double click the Link to make it active

Comment: You can't completely change the question and say that there's still a problem. If your minimal example wasn't able to expose the issue, simply ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

`<Link>` is used for navigating to another page.
If you just want to update a state, you don't need a `<Link>`, just `<ListItem button>` is enough. And both component are interactive (they expect onClick), so maybe that's why you need to double click to go through both click. First click will hit inner most component (ListItem), and the second one hit the outer one (Link). This is call event bubbling.

Ref: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Do this instead.

```
// From this

<Link to="booking" key={1} onClick={() =>  setActiveIndex(1)}>
  <ListItem button className={ (activeIndex === 1 )? classes.activeclass : null}>
    <ListItemIcon><HomeOutlinedIcon fontSize="large"/></ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText><h5>Booking</h5></ListItemText>
  </ListItem>
</Link>

// To this

<ListItem
  button
  key={1}
  onClick={() =>  setActiveIndex(1)}
  className={activeIndex === 1 ? classes.activeclass : null}
>
  <ListItemIcon><HomeOutlinedIcon fontSize="large"/></ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText><h5>Booking</h5></ListItemText>
</ListItem>
```

Comment: yeah the state is changed but link doesn't work!! . Is there a way to change Link and state together??

Comment: I wouldn't recommend. URL and state solve same thing but on different level. What store in state shouldn't be stored in URL, and vise-versa. You can answer this question, do you want the state to be preserved when user refresh the page? If yes, use Link and store page state in URL (like yourpage.com/booking). If no, then store your page in state.

Comment: i want to store state when user changes the page like navbar.Is it possible to store state when page gets refresh.

Comment: It is possible, i might add that it's rarely the case for navigation. "User change page" usually interpret as url change, or state change. Not both at the same time. Multiple source of truth would make application more complex than it should be. On the rare case that you want to pass the state from this page to next page. You can use `history.push` with 2nd parameter. https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/28c89f4091ae9e1b0001341ea60c629674e83627/docs/navigation.md

Comment: `onClick={() =>  {setActiveIndex(1);history.push("/booking", {activeIndex:1});}}` I tried this but it didn't work!!

Comment: yes, that wouldn't work. "setActiveIndex(1)" set a state in that page. When you run history.push, the page change into another page. So whatever state you have on this page would be cleared. If you want to get the state you pass along the .push, you can use "useLocation" from react-router-dom. I put together mini demo for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-proskuriakova-gp0hr?file=/src/App.js:385-419